# javascript object manipulation, code splitting

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have an object that needs to be split up so I can re-use the code.
It's a configuration object for a db.
This is what `mssql`, from the *npm* package, expects to see.

```
const config = {
    user: process.env.USER,
    password: process.env.PASS,
    server: process.env.SERVER,
    database: process.env.DB,

    options: {
        encrypt: false
    }
};
```

I want to seperate it so i can have 2 seperate objects that I can still combine together to use but i'm not sure how to do it.

```
const config = {
    user: process.env.USER,
    password: process.env.PASS,
    server: process.env.SERVER,
    database: process.env.DB
}

const options = {
    encrypt: false
}
```

I want something like this so I can just somehow combine the 2 when using it for `mssql` but then I can still use the `const config` elsewhere without the `options` within it.
Is this possible?
when i combine the two, i've tried
`const mssqlConfig = { connection: config, options };` But that gives me an extra set of `{ }` around `config` that I don't need. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ES2018+, you can use the spread (`...`) operator for spreading object properties onto a new object, which is exactly what you want.

```js
const config = {
  user: "process.env.USER",
  password: "process.env.PASS",
  server: "process.env.SERVER",
  database: "process.env.DB"
}

const options = {
  encrypt: false
}

const mssqlConfig = { ...config, options };

console.log(mssqlConfig);
```

Comment: thank you! I totally forgot about the spread operator. Seems like the cleanest way to do it :)

Answer (score 2):

When you go to use it, make a *copy* of `config` and add `options` to it. You can make a copy using `Object.assign` (it's a shallow copy, but your `config` doesn't have nested objects);

```
var configToUse = Object.assign({}, config);
configToUse.options = options;
```

If you want to copy `options` as well:

```
var configToUse = Object.assign({}, config, {options: Object.assign({}, options)});
```

You could also use ES2018+'s property spread notation:¹

```
const configToUse = {...config, options}; // Doesn't copy options, just uses it
// or
const configToUse = {...config, options: {...options}};
```

---

¹ Yes, really ES2018. *Array* spread was in ES2015, but property spread wasn't until ES2018.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Object.assign` is what you are looking for:

```js
const config = {
  user: "process.env.USER",
  password: "process.env.PASS",
  server: "process.env.SERVER",
  database: "process.env.DB"
}

const options = {
  encrypt: false
}

const both = Object.assign({
  options: options
}, config);
console.log(both);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ES6 you can use the spread operator:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

So something like:

`const mssqlConfig = { ...config, options }`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wanna do is use Object.assign(dest, source), this method will copy the keys from one object to another, an example:

```js
const config = {
    prop1: 'Prop value',
    prop2: 'Prop2 value',
}

const options = {
    encrypt: false
}

Object.assign(config, options);

console.log(config);
```

Run the snippet and you will see the end result, last but not least important [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)